# Example of non compact sets whose union and intersection is compact

Tags: general-topology

Give an example of two non compact sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cup B$ is compact and $A \cap B$ is compact.

My attempt:
Let $A=\{1/n:n=1,2,...\}$ and  $B=\{0\} \cup (1,2]$.
Then $A \cup B$ is closed and bounded so it is compact and $A \cap B$ is empty so it is also compact but $A$ and $B$ are not compact as they are not closed.

Is it correct?

Comment: It’s fine. If you want one in which $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$, you could add a compact set like $[3,4]$ to both $A$ and $B$ off where it won’t interfere with the rest of the example. Or you could do something fancier, like letting $A=[-1,2)$ and $B=[-2,-1)\cup[0,1]\cup[2,3]$, so that $A\cap B=[0,1]$ and $A\cup B=[-2,3]$. And if want **really** non-compact sets, you could use $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ and $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is just fine! Just remember, depending on what this is for, you may want to also show/explain why $A$ and $B$ are not compact (show that $A,B$ have a limit point that they do not contain so that they are not closed, hence not compact). You have justified that $A \cap B$ is compact. It is clear that $A \cup B$ is bounded. You may be expected to verify that $A \cup B$ is closed, which just require a little bit of routine extra work.